# How can I make Excel's MIN function ignore zeroes in a set?

Tags: excel, min

In Excel, I have the following formula `=(MIN(H69,H52,H35,H18)*(1/H18))*10` that is supposed to return the `MIN` of a range, and divide it by the current cell (*(1/H18) ), then multiply by 10.

I am having difficulty with adding a type of NULLIF statement. I want to be able to have (the possibility for) blank rows, and have the MIN function ignore zero/blank fields while selecting the next lowest value (all are between 1.0-0.1).

Is there a modifier i can apply to the MIN function to make it not compare zeroes in the MIN set? Is there a better function than `MIN` to use?

Here is the arrangement:
[image]

- Please remember to include the syntax for where the `MIN`'s set goes
- The reason for the `H69,H52,H35,H18` using commas is that these are embedded, individual cells that are arranged for visual presentation as well. Using a range, or colon/semi-colon operators don't appear to work for this purpose (see pic).
- This is to prevent the following situation: *users* will need to eliminate fields that are zeros from the form, theres 2 formula edits per entry, averaging 4 entries per use, so 8 possible errors per form use...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A100>0,A1:A100))
```

You will need to hit ctrl+shift+enter to activate this formula.

Comment: could you expand to clarify the syntax? I'm not sure where the set parameters (H69,H52,H35,H18) go.

Comment: So where i have 'A1:A100' this is your cell range, in the example i gave it will action the range cell A1,A2,A3...A100.
This is where you need to enter your data in this format, i am assuming all cells in column H are going to have data in, if not i would consider restructuring your workbook.
You could do: =MIN(IF(H1:H100>0,H1:H100)) {pressing ctrl+shift+enter} Where 100 is the row with the max data in
Or if you have a heading in cell 1 then you could do:
=MIN(IF(H2:H100>0,H2:H100))

Comment: So I followed through and set up a side area with the numbers, there are 12 cells, 9 of which were still `#DIV/0!` and the formula was still spitting out DIV as the MIN answer. I adjusted to make all of the cell references use `SUM` for their values (originally they were an average). Presto, works. Summary; set up proper array (duh), used formula that can add up to zero without values (average cannot), and array>0 worked. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me in Excel 2013, but I had to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
=SMALL(A1:A3,COUNTIF(A1:A3,0)+1)
```

Comment: could you expand to clarify the syntax? I'm not sure where the set parameters (H69,H52,H35,H18) go.

Comment: 99% sure this is just not possible with a simple syntax. Just put them somewhere in a proper range if you want to make life easy.

Comment: Although I was able to make the other solution work, thanks for reinforcing 'Just put them somewhere in a proper range'