# Excel - Return Smallest Value Greater Than 0 of a Certain Type

Tags: excel, min

I am developing a personal finance spreadsheet and want to return values from a range of data which satisfies multiple criteria.

I want the spreadsheet to return the smallest value greater than zero which is of the type CREDIT.

I have tried a few combinations of the `MIN` function, but to no avail.

I want something along the lines of:

```
IF(value>0)
AND(type="CREDIT")
RETURN(value)
```

****UPDATE****

Example: Say I have one hundred values within the range `value`, of which ten belong to the `type` CREDIT and three of those ten are less than zero - I want to return the smallest `value` which is greater than zero.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: **Is the type entered in an adjacent cell or in the same cell as the value??**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628524/how-can-i-make-excels-min-function-ignore-zeroes-in-a-set?rq=1

Comment: `type` is a named range which resides on another worksheet within the workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data like:

[image: sample]

Use the array formula:

```
=MIN(IF((B1:B10="Credit")*(A1:A10>0),A1:A10))
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: We need to get a better view of your data!

Comment: Apologies - I have now figured it out and your solution does indeed work correctly.  Many thanks.